# Memcache_connect Connection timed out

Tags: connection, memcached, solaris, time-wait

I get 10 to 20 of these errors all within 1 second of each other:

> Memcache_connect Connection timed out

This happens several times a day, on a server with about 2500 daily active users, 1GB of ram.  I don't think the server is swapping.  Most of the time, I'm at less then 75% memory utilization, and less then 25% CPU utilization.  The load averages are usually less then 9.  I followed the debugging instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Timeouts

Here are my memcache stats:

```
stats
STAT pid 15365
STAT uptime 173776
STAT time 1329157234
STAT version 1.2.8
STAT pointer_size 32
STAT rusage_user 1171.316354
STAT rusage_system 7046.435826
STAT curr_items 28494
STAT total_items 4039745
STAT bytes 3371127
STAT curr_connections 36
STAT total_connections 102206685
STAT connection_structures 328
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_get 73532547
STAT cmd_set 4039745
STAT get_hits 40779162
STAT get_misses 32753385
STAT evictions 0
STAT bytes_read     2153565193
STAT bytes_written 38768040520
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
STAT threads 2
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
```

My hypothesis is that I'm running out of TIME_WAIT buckets:

```
netstat -n | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l

51892
```

But I don't know if that's too high or not.
I'm on Solaris (on the Joyent servers) and the `tcp_time_wait_interval` is set to 60000.  Some other readings suggested decreasing this setting to 30000, or 15000.  But this doesn't seem like a scalable solution to me.

How do I know that it's running out of buckets?  Should i increase the number of TIME_WAIT buckets? if so, how?